# Merge two SELECT queries into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, logic

I have two queries where I only need the count of total records but the only difference in the queries is one field value.

Example;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS group_a
FROM tbl
WHERE category = 'value_a'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS group_b
FROM tbl
WHERE category = 'value_b'
```

How can I get something like this: (pseudo)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS group_a, COUNT(*) AS group_b
FROM tbl
WHERE category IN ('value_a', 'value_b')
```

But the results are like this

```
group_a , group_b
56, 101
```

I was thinking a CASE statement in the query to filter the two but how do I implement it? or is there a better way?

I'm doing a UNION right now but wanted to know if I could return one record with two results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select sum(case when category = 'value_a' then 1 else 0 end) as group_a,
       sum(case when category = 'value_b' then 1 else 0 end) as group_b
    from tbl
    where category in ('value_a', 'value_b')
```

Comment: Note that the where clause would only help if column "category" is indexed

Comment: +1 to compensate the downvote. Downvote without explanation is not very polite. Maybe you're right, show us the arguments.

Comment: @Frank: Thanks and I agree. I don't mind a downvote when I'm wrong (and I can make a mistake just like anyone), but I do dislike anonymous downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  sum(case when category = 'value_a' then 1 else 0 end) group_a,
        sum(case when category = 'value_b' then 1 else 0 end) group_b
from tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT category,COUNT(*) FROM tbl
GROUP BY category;
```

That expands to more categories. If you want just those categories

```
SELECT category,COUNT(*) FROM tbl
WHERE category IN ('value_a', 'value_b')
GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: You should add a WHERE category IN ('value_a', 'value_b') to it.

Comment: Damn you Internets, you're fast.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The task was to fit the groups into a single row.

Comment: I do like the simple GROUP BY so +1, but needed in a single row return

Comment: Return the whole result set, not row by row, surely? It does the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

What strange answers for counting. Here's a straightforward COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(category = 'value_a' OR NULL) AS group_a, COUNT(category = 'value_b' OR NULL) AS group_b FROM tbl;
```

The COUNT aggregate in PostgreSQL allows complex syntax like I've shown. Note that the `OR NULL` is quite essential as COUNT counts only those rows for which the condition `category = '...' OR NULL` gives non-NULL answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT category
    FROM tbl 
) subquery
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(category)
    FOR category IN ([value_a],[value_b])
) AS piv
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice PostgreSQL.  But if you were using MS SQL 2005+, the pivot is a cool feature.

Comment: PostgreSQL has the pivot as well, it's a contrib module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html